# JetBrains. How sync all config files with Settings Repository plugin

Tags: plugins, synchronization, phpstorm, settings, jetbrains-ide

Settings Repository plugin syncs not all config files e.g.: `project.default.xml`, `watcherDefaultTasks.xml`, `window.state.xml`.

**Is there a way to include them in synced files?**

As far as I understand plugin has settings that are stored in:
`settingsRepository/config.json`. However, I did not find a list of available settings and their descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to include an arbitrary config file in Settings Repository, unfortunately.
Here are issue tracker links for the missing config files:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174516/Settings-repository-missing-settings
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292900/Ability-to-sync-File-Watchers-through-Settings-Repository